# Create a dynamic bar chart using ajax toolkit extension in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, bar-chart, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have recorded events that happen during a football such as Goal, Wide Shot, Free Conceded, Yellow Card etc. These are stored in my SQL DB. I want to create a dynamic bar chart using the ajax toolkit for my asp.net web form. I want the Y axis of my chart to show the names of these events and the X axis to show the number of times each of these events happens over the course of a match.

I need to count each time one of the events occurs in my DB however I am not sure how to do that.

This is what my DB table looks like.
[image]

Below is the code that I already have however the bar chart is empty whenever I view it.

```
             sqlcon. Open();
                      SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
                      * FROM Events WHERE  FixtureID = " + 
                      ddlFixture.SelectedValue, sqlcon);
                      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                      sqlda.Fill(ds);
                      BarChart1.Visible = true;
                      string[] events = new string[15];
                      string[] count = new string[15];

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                count[0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EventName"].ToString();

                events[0] = "Point";
                events[1] = "Goal";
                events[2] = "Wide";
                events[3] = "Break";
                events[4] = "Free Con";
                events[5] = "Free Won";
                events[6] = "Mark";
                events[7] = "Block";
                events[8] = "Yellow";
                events[9] = "Red";
                events[10] = "Black";
                events[11] = "T/O Won";
                events[12] = "T/O Lost";
                events[13] = "Kickout Won";
                events[14] = "Kickout Lost";
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
BarChart1.DataSource = YourDTable;//or ds.Tables[0]
BarChart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
BarChart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Time";
BarChart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "EventName";
BarChart1.DataBind();
```

If I understand correctly, then maybe your decision may be so. I think better method use chart js or another chart, and solve it with ajax.